# How to fill ParentID column in one update statement?

Tags: sql-server

My table is like this:

```
ID  Code  ParentID
-------------------
1   A01    NULL
2   B83    NULL
3   H92    NULL
15  A013   NULL
23  A018   NULL
33  A01899 NULL
44  B8329  NULL
67  B83293 NULL
```

What I want is to update `ParentID` to match the ID of the parent code.

- A01 is the parent for A013
- A01 is the parent for A018
- A018 is the parent for A01899

and so on.

You can see the length of `A01` is 3 while the child `A013` length is 4, the length of `A018` is 4 and the child `A01899` length is 6.

I can do that with multiple update statements and repeat that for each case.

```
UPDATE A
SET ParentID = B.ID
FROM Table A 
INNER JOIN Table B ON A.Code like B.Code + '%'
WHERE LEN(A.Code) = 4 AND LEN(B.Code) = 3
```

But the question is how to do that in a single `update` statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first find all the relevant matches - similar to what you have - but also the length of the code it matched to. Then find the one with the longest matched code.

```
CREATE TABLE #TableA (ID int, Code varchar(10), ParentID int);
INSERT INTO #TableA (ID, Code, ParentID)
VALUES
(1 ,  'A01'   , NULL),
(2 ,  'B83'   , NULL),
(3 ,  'H92'   , NULL),
(15,  'A013'  , NULL),
(23,  'A018'  , NULL),
(33,  'A01899', NULL),
(44,  'B8329' , NULL),
(67,  'B83293', NULL);


WITH A AS
(SELECT TA.ID, TA.ParentID, TB.ID AS TB_ID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TA.ID ORDER BY TB.Len_Code DESC) AS rn
  FROM #TableA TA
       INNER JOIN 
          (SELECT ID, Code, LEN(CODE) AS Len_Code
             FROM #TableA
          ) TB ON TA.Code LIKE TB.Code + '%'
  WHERE TA.ID <> TB.ID
) 
UPDATE  A
  SET   A.ParentId = A.TB_ID
  WHERE A.rn = 1;
```

Result

```
ID  Code    ParentID
1   A01     NULL
2   B83     NULL
3   H92     NULL
15  A013    1
23  A018    1
33  A01899  23
44  B8329   2
67  B83293  44
```

Answer (score 2):

Just another option.

Significant Digits can be a risky business in the long run.  It has been my experience that they tend to have a rather short shelf-life until an exception needs to be made.

In the example below, we allow for up to three characters in distance.  We apply the closest first via the `coalesce()`

Just to be clear, `Left Join D` may not be necessary if Parents are within 1 or 2 characters.  Conversely, this could be expanded if needed  `Left Join D ...`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] int,[Code] varchar(50),[ParentID] int)
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'A01',NULL)
,(2,'B83',NULL)
,(3,'H92',NULL)
,(15,'A013',NULL)
,(23,'A018',NULL)
,(33,'A01899',NULL)
,(44,'B8329',NULL)
,(67,'B83293',NULL)

;with cte as ( 
Select A.*
      ,PtNr = coalesce(B.ID,C.ID,D.ID) 
 From  @YourTable A
 Left Join @YourTable B on left(A.[Code],len(A.[Code])-1)=B.[Code]
 Left Join @YourTable C on left(A.[Code],len(A.[Code])-2)=C.[Code] 
 Left Join @YourTable D on left(A.[Code],len(A.[Code])-3)=D.[Code] 
)
Update cte set ParentID=PtNr

Select * From @YourTable
```

**The Update Table**

```
ID  Code    ParentID
1   A01     NULL
2   B83     NULL
3   H92     NULL
15  A013    1
23  A018    1
33  A01899  23
44  B8329   2
67  B83293  44
```